# youtube-dl delete files that are no longer in a playlist

Tags: command-line, youtube, youtube-dl

I have a watch later playlist on YouTube. I both add videos to it and remove watched ones constantly. I use

```
youtube-dl <playlist_url>
```

to download the entire playlist into a current folder. The idea is to keep this folder in sync with the playlist, in other words to delete videos from the local folder that are no longer in the playlist.
Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Does this do what you want? https://github.com/chewett/youtube

Comment: @jrtapsell the link is broken for me

Comment: My phone cut it off... https://github.com/chewett/youtube-playlist-sync/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @jrtapsell exactly what i wanted

Comment: I'll make an answer for it

Comment: Hi, the OP asked about deletion. How can I use this mentioned script to also delete the files locally if they are no longer in the online playlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing it yourself, you can use this script to keep a folder in sync with a playlist:

https://github.com/chewett/youtube-playlist-sync/blob/master/README.md

To set it up you run:

```
yps.py --init <playlist url> --dir <folder>
```

To sync you run:

```
yps.py --sync <folder>
```

Comment: Hi, the OP asked about deletion.  How can I use this mentioned script to also delete the files locally if they are no longer in the online playlist?